# Apache Beam Not Saving Unbounded Data To Text File

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've created a Pipeline to save Google Cloud Pubsub messages into text files using Apache Beam and Java.
Whenever I run the pipeline within Google Dataflow with `--runner=DataflowRunner` the messages are saved correctly.

However, when I run the same pipeline with `--runner=DirerctRunner` the messages are not saved.

I can watch the events coming through the pipeline, but nothing happens.

The pipeline is the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExerciseOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(ExerciseOptions.class);

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    pipeline
      .apply("Read Messages from Pubsub",
        PubsubIO
          .readStrings()
          .fromTopic(options.getTopicName()))

      .apply("Set event timestamp", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
          context.outputWithTimestamp(context.element(), Instant.now());
        }
      }))

      .apply("Windowing", Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(5))))

      .apply("Write to File",
        TextIO
          .write()
          .withWindowedWrites()
          .withNumShards(1)
          .to(options.getOutputPrefix()));

    pipeline.run();
  }
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to run this pipeline locally?

Comment: That looks like a bug in the DirectRunner, I filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5488

Comment: Someone was able to resolve this? Any workaround maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem.
`PubSubIO` was not working correctly with `DirectRunner` and `TextIO`. I found a workaround for this issue with window triggering before the write. For some runners, this needs the `--streaming` tag to work.

```java
  pipeline
    .apply("2 minutes window", 
        Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(2)))
          .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterFirst.of(
                      AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(10),
                      AfterProcessingTime
                          .pastFirstElementInPane()
                          .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(2)))))
          .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(10))
          .discardingFiredPanes())
```

This way the files are written as expected.

Comment: Wow...after several hours of frustration this fixed me up! Thanks!